# open device calendar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

We need to open the device calendar from an icon onpressed event, is this possible? We are already using the calendar plugin to grab events but we want to open the month view of the devices calendar, not pull them into dart.

Comment: It would help if you shared the plugin you are using for other camera operations to see if offers a mechanism. You could also probably use other plugins like `url_launcher` to get what you want.

Comment: does url_launcher have an option for calendar? I didnt think it did.

Comment: On iOS you could use the calshow:// URL scheme (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820762/does-ios-calendar-support-a-url-scheme). Not sure on Android, worst case you could use the `android_intent` plugin like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382005/how-to-open-google-calendar-app-from-my-app/23382408

Comment: only way to launch an application is know package name, and this mean if you set google calendar package name and user hasn't google calendar installed on phone you cant launch it

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to support Android, iOS, and web. A blanket approach for opening Calendars is by opening a URL with .ics or other formats that supports the Calendar standard ([RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-8.1)) using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). Apple Calendar and Google Calendar URLs are supported. Another option here is using [webcal://](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal) URI.