# User Pick Calendar Event

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

How would I have a user pick an event from their device calendar?

[Android Calendar Provider Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12902697/3502776) state that you can view the calendar using an Intent like so:

```
long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

// using content://com.android.calendar/time/<ms_since_epoch>

Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("time");
ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(builder.build());
startActivity(intent);
```

However, this only allows us to open the calendar for viewing, using intents.

How would I have the intent return the event ID upon selection?

---

UPDATE 1: For grins, looking in the Developers Guide, I'm going to try to do a [`Intent.ACTION_PICK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK) instead of `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. `ACTION_PICK` isn't defined in the Calendar Provider but its worth a shot. Note that `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` did work previously.

**UPDATE 2**: As probably expected, the runtime threw this when using ACTION_PICK:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.calendar/time/1475990157934 }
```

***It seems using intents are out of the question?***

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your device have no `Calendar` application.
I would advice you to use `intent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager() != null` check every time you are trying to send an implicit intent. 
The only way to get calendar information without `Calendar` app is to use a calendar content provider like it's described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html?hl=en)

Comment: Let me clarify my updates, ACTION_VIEW did open the Calendar app but ACTION_PICK threw the error.