# Open Android Calendar with Intent from Web (Chrome)

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, android-intent, calendar

You can [open Android apps from within Chrome using HTML links](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents).

And I know that an intent from within an Android app to open the calendar is `content://com.android.calendar/time` ([How to use Calendar Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617231/how-to-use-calendar-intent/42540989#42540989))

**Now I want to create a HTML link to open the calendar app from within Chrome.** Note, this is a scenario where **my app is not installed** on the Android device. So I cannot create App intents to redirect to the calendar app.

I imagine something like this:

```
intent://time#Intent;scheme=content;package=com.android.calendar;end
```

Unfortunately that link doesn't work — it opens a "Not found" page in the Play Store.

What am I missing? What would the link need to look like?

*Source: [Calendar App Manifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/marshmallow-release/AndroidManifest.xml)*

*Possible duplicate: [open android calendar with html link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209476/open-android-calendar-with-html-link)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open an activity from a browser the activity's intent-filter must have the [BROWSABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE) category.

If you look at the `AndroidManifest.xml` from the Google Calendar app you referenced, there exists only one such activity: `com.android.calendar/.GoogleCalendarUriIntentFilter`. This activity accepts URLs to calendar events, including URLs that start with https://www.google.com/calendar/event.

If you don't mind the short warning message that the opened event doesn't exist, you could use this link to open the Calendar app from a browser. If you prefer an intent link, you could also use `intent://www.google.com/calendar/event#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.google.android.calendar;end`, but unfortunately you won't be able to start `com.android.calendar/.AllInOneActivity`, the activity listening for `content://...` URLs, directly from the browser.

Comment: The short warning message isn't that obtrusive. Great solution!

Comment: I am confused, so you mean to say that change 'http' from the event invite link to 'intent' to open Android calendar?

Comment: Just try both links! Both open the Google calendar app, so use whichever you prefer.

Comment: Remove 'event' from the URL and you won't see any warning.